# Powershell Array is printing the item index along with values

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-ise

I am returning the array in Powershell. But in response, I am getting array values along with the indexes of the respective values.

How I can stop the item index from printing in the console.

Code Example:

```html
$data = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$Item1 = "vimal" +"::"+ "error1"      
$data.add($Item1)
$Item1 = "vimal" +"::"+ "error2"      
$data.add($Item1)

return $data
```

Response:

0
1
vimal::error1
vimal::error2

I don't want to print 0 and 1 in the console.

Thanks,
Vimal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayList.Add` returns index of an newly-added object. Those returns (all un-catched returns) are joined together

```
$data = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$Item1 = "vimal" +"::"+ "error1"      
$data.add($Item1)   # <<== This outputs "0" because Add() returns index (0) of added object
$Item1 = "vimal" +"::"+ "error2"      
$data.add($Item1)   # <<== This outputs "1"

return $data  # <<== This outputs "..error1" and "..error2"
```

To suppress unwanted returns, use `[void]$data.add(...)` or `$data.add(...) | Out-Null` or assign value to some var: `$indexOfItem1 = $data.add(...)`